# Facebook Iframe link only open within the iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe

I feel like people have been having the opposite of this problem, I cannot figure how to have links open up outside of fb and not with the iframe.. I am posting material that rests in an FB app hosted by my server. The page has links to other sites, but when they open up they are still in the facebook iframe.

using basic:

```
<a href= "http...."><b>Blank.com</b>
```

looks like this
Click link...

I'm a rookie and any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

target="_blank" works if you have set up an app for the iframe.

Comment: i wonder if there's an option so it doesn't open in a new window, but does a full page refresh and links properly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `target` attribute?

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">example.com</a>
```